Merging 2 excel sheet in Python
I have 2 separate excel sheets with multiple rows - Excel_1, Excel_2. Both the excels have same column names.
Excel_1
col1  col2  col3  col4
 1     1     2     4
 4     3     2     1

Excel_2
col1  col2  col3  col4
  3     2     2    1
  5     3     1    0

I want a merged excel sheet, of this format.
Merged_excel
 col1_1  col2_1  col3_1  col4_1  col1_2  col2_2  col3_2  col4_2
   1       1       2       4        3       2       2       1
   4       3       2       1        5       3       1       0

Tried using append, but couldn't get the above mentioned format.

Try: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).

Don't use append anyway it's deprecated, read the excels as dataframes using pd.read_excel() and then merge using concat,
df1 = pd.read_excel("excel 1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("excel 2.xlsx")

merged_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)

